# Style of writing conditional operators

Tags: coding-style

What is considered more appropriate style of writing conditional operators?

```
if(1){
  puts("Hello")
}
```

or

```
 if(1) puts("Hello")
```

Similar aspects of coding style are welcome too.

Comment: Why the `if(1)`? You can make it just: `puts("Hello")`

Comment: What do you consider "more appropriate"? Both versions work (there are some others that do as well) and the only answer i can think of is: "Whatever your Coding Conventions tell you"

Comment: The question is actually about choosing between those conventions and standarts of coding. Which one would you recommend?

Comment: @Michał, it's just an example to illustrate the actual question.

Comment: Always always always use braces.

Comment: @aliteralmind, what about 
`if(1) { puts("Hello")}`, then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's all depends on your preference, that's why we rarely see people code in the same style.. Moreover, it depends on which programming language you're using.. IMHO, the important thing in coding is code **readability** and **comments**, so when your BOSS asks other people to help or develop your code. He /she will spend the least amount of their time to understand your code..

If you ask specifically from your example above, I would prefer the first one.. Because in my OPINION, imagining the WHOLE code, that one will give better readability. HOWEVER, some people may argue that it will spend some of your time typing those brackets over and over..

Answer (score 0):

As per the PSR standards any structure must always enclose the code in parentheses.

**The body of each structure MUST be enclosed by braces. This standardizes how the structures look, and reduces the likelihood of introducing errors as new lines get added to the body.**
from the official website

Please have a look under control structures section http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/